# Закрашивание клетки даты в QCalendarWidget | PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

Очередной вопрос от меня по PyQT5 и QCalendarWidget...

Вопрос следующий. У меня есть календарь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть должна быть такова, я добавляю задачу и отрисовывается красная точка в уголке указанной даты.
При запуске приложения они прекрасно отрисовываются и всё работает, но при добавлении новой задачи на день, где задачи не было, точка не появляется. Вопрос в том, как принудительно отрисовать эту точку.

Это код самого класса (в нем собраны уже и календарь, и остальные элементы в окне)
`main.py`

```
class Window(QWidget, main_ui.Ui_Form):

def __init__(self, _us_id):

    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.user_id = _us_id
    self.timeEdit
    self.calendarWidget.selectionChanged.connect(self.calendar_date_changed)
    self.calendar_date_changed()
    self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.save_changes)
    self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_new_task)
    self.closeButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
    self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

def calendar_date_changed(self):

    dateSelected = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
    self.update_task_list(dateSelected)

def update_task_list(self, date):

    if check_connection() is True:

        self.tasksListWidget.clear()
        self.timeTasksListWidget.clear()

        if (str(self.user_id) in tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"].keys()) and \
                (str(date) in tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"][str(self.user_id)].keys()):

            results = tmp.read()["data"]["tasks"][str(self.user_id)][str(date)]
            for key in results.keys():

                item_task = QListWidgetItem(f'{key}')
                item_time = QListWidgetItem(f'{results[key][0]}')
                item_task.setFlags(item_task.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)

                if results[key][1] is True:
                    item_task.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
                elif results[key][1] is False:
                    item_task.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.tasksListWidget.addItem(item_task)
                self.timeTasksListWidget.addItem(item_time)

    else:
        notification.notify(message='Нестабильное интерент подключение. Изменения не будут сохранены',
                            app_name='Daily Task Planner', title='Проблемы :(', app_icon = r'icon.ico')

def add_new_task(self):
    def check_len(string):
        if len(str(string)) == 1:
            return f'0{string}'
        else:
            return f'{string}'

    task = str(self.taskLineEdit.text())
    date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
    time = f'{check_len(self.timeEdit.time().hour())}:{check_len(self.timeEdit.time().minute())}'
    tmp.add_task(self.user_id, date, task, time, False)
    self.update_task_list(date)
    self.taskLineEdit.clear()

def save_changes(self):

    date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
    for i in range(self.tasksListWidget.count()):

        item = self.tasksListWidget.item(i)
        task = item.text()
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            tmp.edit_task_status(str(self.user_id), date, task, True)
        else:
            tmp.edit_task_status(str(self.user_id), date, task, False)

    messageBox = QMessageBox()
    messageBox.setText("Changes saved.")
    messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
    messageBox.exec()
```

Код самого календаря в другом файле (создан через QTDesigner и конвертирован в .py файл)
Перегрузка для отрисовки даты есть (просто я не совсем понимаю как вызвать что-то подобное в main файле) `ui.py`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt


import tmp


class MyCalendar(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.events = tmp.get_dates(str(861241888))

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):

        QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
        if self.events is not None:
            if date in self.events:
                painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
                painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)




class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(872, 513)
        self.calendarWidget = MyCalendar(Form)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 160, 411, 311))
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet("font:12pt;\n"
"selection-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"selection-background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);")
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.tasksListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.tasksListWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 160, 241, 301))
        self.tasksListWidget.setStyleSheet("font:12pt;")
        self.tasksListWidget.setObjectName("tasksListWidget")
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 470, 341, 28))
        self.saveButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"font:11pt;")
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.addButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 120, 93, 28))
        self.addButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"")
        self.addButton.setObjectName("addButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 851, 101))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font-size : 24pt;\n"
"background-color: rgb(170, 0, 255);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"border-radius:8px;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.taskLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.taskLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 120, 241, 31))
        self.taskLineEdit.setStyleSheet("font:12pt;")
        self.taskLineEdit.setObjectName("taskLineEdit")
        self.timeTasksListWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.timeTasksListWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 160, 91, 301))
        self.timeTasksListWidget.setStyleSheet("font:12pt;")
        self.timeTasksListWidget.setObjectName("timeTasksListWidget")
        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(Form)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 120, 118, 22))
        self.timeEdit.setObjectName("timeEdit")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 851, 501))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 224, 252);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.closeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 20, 21, 21))
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius:10px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 156, 205);\n"
"color:white;\n"
"font:11pt;")
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.calendarWidget.raise_()
        self.tasksListWidget.raise_()
        self.saveButton.raise_()
        self.addButton.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.taskLineEdit.raise_()
        self.timeTasksListWidget.raise_()
        self.timeEdit.raise_()
        self.closeButton.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Сохранить изменения"))
        self.addButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Создать задачу"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Планировщик дня"))
        self.taskLineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введи свою задачу тут"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас список событий в календаре заполняется только при инициализации календарика и больше нигде не трогается.Вам надо изменять список событий в календарике при вводе новых задач. К примеру так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton,QCalendarWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint

class MyCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QCalendarWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.events = []
    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
        if date in self.events:
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(12, 7), 3, 3)

class Main(QWidget):
    def setClicked(self):
        if self.calendar.selectedDate() in self.calendar.events:
            self.calendar.events.remove(self.calendar.selectedDate())
        else:
            self.calendar.events.append(self.calendar.selectedDate())
        # force widget update
        self.calendar.hide()
        self.calendar.show()


    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Образец')
        self.resize(500, 300)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.calendar = MyCalendar()
        self.button = QPushButton("set/reset")
        grid.addWidget(self.calendar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.setClicked)



if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```